# How to Get parameter value from URL like any MVC in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

Actually i'm new to php website development, i want to get the value from url like any Model-View-Controller can do:

```
www.domain.com/index/var_value
```

Here 'www.domain.com'  is my domain name and **index** is my name or php page name and **var_value** is my parameter. This pattern can see on any MVC,

So the question is how to do like this in core PHP.

I already tried to chnage in .htaccess file to got solution but can't found exact solution that i want.
Please help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You've got a lot of stuff going on here. Step 1 is that data in the URL is sent via GET so your $_POST won't work. Step 2 is to get pretty URLs working within your web server configuration.

Comment: Actually I want to access the value get is not i mean GET here

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how I interpret it...

URL

`http://www.mypage.com?key=value&key2=value2`

PHP Page

```
<?php
    $value = $_GET['key'];
    $value2 = $_GET['key2'];

    echo $value;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $value2;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but i didn't mean that.

Comment: URL-http://www.mypage.com?key=value&key2=value2 and what is the php code and rewrite rule for 'http://www.mypage.com/value'